# What are the failure modes of transaction.atomic()?

Tags: django, transactions

I'm unclear on the exact behaviour of Django in the face of database serialization errors in transactions.

The docs [`transaction.atomic()` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) don't specify this behaviour as far as I can tell.

If the DB hits a consistency error while committing a transaction (e.g. another transaction updated a value that was read in the current transaction), reading `django.db.transaction.py`, it looks like the transaction will rollback, and the DatabaseError will be raised to the calling code (e.g. the transaction.atomic() context manager). Is this correct?

And, more importantly, are there cases when the transaction could be rolled back without the transaction.atomic wrapper receiving an exception?

(Note that I'm not asking about DatabaseErrors that are raised *inside* the context manager, as the docs clearly explain what happens to them. I'm asking only about database errors which occur during the commit of the transaction, which occurs on exit of the context manager.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the DB hits a consistency error while committing a transaction ... it looks like the transaction will rollback, and the DatabaseError will be raised to the calling code (e.g. the transaction.atomic() context manager). Is this correct?

Yes, precisely.

> Are there cases when the transaction could be rolled back without the transaction.atomic wrapper receiving an exception?

No. You can verify this from the code inside `transaction.py` where the only time a rollback is initiated is if `DatabaseError` is thrown. This is also confirmed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) that you link to:

> When exiting an atomic block, Django looks at whether it’s exited normally or with an exception to determine whether to commit or roll back.

Comment: So, a follow-up question -- if you always get an exception, why do we need `transaction.on_commit()` that was added in Django 1.9? Seems like we could always say `try: <transaction> except DatabaseError: <handle> else: <do on_commit stuff>`

Comment: `on_commit` works for all transactions, not just atomic ones.